# Verificar usuarios vip vencido

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Boa tarde pessoal,

Eu tenho um portal de classificados e estou colocando contas VIP nele, estas contas terão a possibilidade de fazer uma quantia de postagens vip pelo plano contratado.
Eu já sei como evitar que ela continue usufruindo dos benefícios de VIP depois da data do vencimento mas não descobri uma forma simples de resetar os anúncios que estavam vip até o momento.
Eu salvo a data do vencimento do vip do usuário desta forma na tabela do banco de dados 2016-12-02 em string.
OBS* eu salvo a data do vencimento na tabela usuario e na tabela anuncios eu marco se o anúncio é vip ou não.

Alguém saberia me dizer como fazer uma cronjob que funcione com esta data e retire o campo vip dos posts ?

Obrigado

Comment: Pra que tudo isso de complicação? `$usuario_e_vip = $vencimentovip >= date()` - nao precisa mudar nada na data basta verificar se é ou não na hora que quiser - Quanto a salvar data em string, não tem sentido nenhum isso. Se usa DB, data é em formato data, ou no máximo em um inteiro. Simplifique, fica mais fácil de manter, e funciona melhor. Evite misturar formato de armazenagem com formato de exibição, raramente alguém precisa disso num caso real (e a maioria que acha que precisa costuma estar enganada)

Comment: A mesma lógica funciona no DB se for exibir os anuncios, `SELECT campos FROM tabela WHERE vencimentovip >= CURRENT_DATE`